# Programa para fazer perguntas de multiplicação

Tags: python, python-2.7

Pretendo fazer um programa em Python (2.7.14) que gere dois números aleatoriamente (de 0 a 10), multiplique-os, pergunte o resultado para o usuário, e exiba se o resultado está correto ou errado, até que seja digitada a *string* "fim", meu código ficou assim:

```
    import random

    m = 0

    while m!="fim" :
        n1=int(random.random()*10)
        n2=int(random.random()*10)

        m = raw_input("{} * {} = ".format(n1,n2))  
        mult = int(n1*n2)

        if m==mult :
            print "correto!"

        else :
            print "errado!!"
```

Porém, sempre que eu digito algo, o programa sempre imprime "errado!!" , Qual o erro no meu código? Ele está bem escrito? É possível otimizá-lo mais? Se sim , como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas, além de estar comparando uma *string*  com um número, deixar digitar um texto onde se espera um número não parece ser uma boa ideia. Claro que pode tratar a exceção gerada. Não seria uma má ideia já que é um erro possível. Mas para simplificar preferi só mudar a entrada que indica o fim.

Os números gerados também estavam errados, gerava 0 que eu imagino que não é o que deseja, já que isto parece ser caso de tabuada. Se realmente quer 0, pode voltar ao 10 como estava.

```
import random
m = 1
while m != 0:
    n1 = int(random.random() * 9) + 1
    n2 = int(random.random() * 9) + 1
    m = int(raw_input("{} * {} = ".format(n1, n2)))
    print ("correto!" if m == n1 * n2 else "errado!!")
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2q50Jy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/coougtoq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/RandomGuess.py).

Answer (score 0):

Se você fizer `type(m)` e `type(mult)` vai ver que o primeiro é um `str` enquanto o segundo é `int`.

Pra resolver é só modificar o `if`, fazendo uma conversão da variável `m` para inteiro:

```
if int(m)==mult :
    print "correto!"
else :
    print "errado!!"
```